# How to group and assign group ID to duplicate values in column of table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

My question involves the use of SQL to assign multiple groups of duplicated values a group id, through the use of a script. I've been doing it by hand for a bit and realized that, with the expanse of the database (a couple thousand elements), it would take ages.

Here is my DB structure:

```
id  | db quesition         | db keywords           | answer id  | db answer                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  | Why is Mars red?     | [why,mars,red]        | 0          | Mars is red because blah     |

 1  | How is Mars red?     | [how,mars,red]        | 0          | Mars is red because blah     |

 2  | What makes Mars red? | [what,makes,mars,red] | 0          | Mars is red because blah     |

 3  | Is Mars very rocky?  | [is,mars,rocky]       | 0          | Yes Mars is rocky blahbla    |

 4  | Does Mars have rocks?| [mars,have,rocks]     | 0          | Yes Mars is rocky blahbla    |

 5  | What is the Sun?     | [what,is,sun]         | 0          | The Sun is our solar blah    |

 6  | What is a star?      | [what,is,star]        | 0          | A star is a ball of hot blah |
```

Now, as you can see, there can be multiple questions for one answer, therefore the database will have duplicates in the `db_answer` column. I would like for each `db_answer` to have a singular `answer_id` that would be repeated if the answer is used more than once. To illustrate, I'd like for my db to look like:

```
id  | db quesition         |  db keywords          | answer id | db answer                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  | Why is Mars red?     | [why,mars,red]        | 1         | Mars is red because blah     |

 1  | How is Mars red?     | [how,mars,red]        | 1         | Mars is red because blah     |

 2  | What makes Mars red? | [what,makes,mars,red] | 1         | Mars is red because blah     |

 3  | Is Mars very rocky?  | [is,mars,rocky]       | 2         | Yes Mars is rocky blahbla    |

 4  | Does Mars have rocks?| [mars,have,rocks]     | 2         | Yes Mars is rocky blahbla    |

 5  | What is the Sun?     | [what,is,sun]         | 3         | The Sun is our solar blah    |

 6  | What is a star?      | [what,is,star]        | 4         | A star is a ball of hot blah |
```

I have looked extensively for scripts that do this, but haven't had any luck. Just as a note to show what I've been trying to do, I have been using the SQL for each answer group I wanted to add an id to:

```
UPDATE elements SET answer_id = '1' WHERE db_answer = 'Mars is red because blah'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be pretty easy with a PHP script:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT db_answer FROM elements");
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE elements SET answer_id = {$i} WHERE db_answer = '{$row[0]}'");
    $i++;
}
```

However, I think it might be wise to store the answers in a separate table and just keep the `answer_id` in the `elements` table. That way you avoid unnecessarily duplicating information.

---

**EDIT :**

As @mdoyle suggested, I think it would be best to use four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    questionID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    question VARCHAR(128),
    answerID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (questionID),
    FOREIGN KEY (answerID) REFERENCES answers (answerID)
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
    answerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    answer VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (answerID)
);

CREATE TABLE keywords (
    keywordID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    keyword VARCHAR(16),
    PRIMARY KEY (keywordID)
);

CREATE TABLE question_keywords (
    questionID INT,
    keywordID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (questionID) REFERENCES questions (questionID),
    FOREIGN KEY (keywordID) REFERENCES keywords (keywordID)
);
```

The relationship between the `answers` table and the `questions` table is *one-to-many* (**one** answer may apply to **many** questions), so you have two tables. This assumes that each question can have one and only one answer. If this isn't the case, and there is a possibility that one question might have two acceptable answers, then the relationship becomes *many-to-many* (continue reading for how to set up tables for a many-to-many relationship).

The relationship between the `questions` table and the `keywords` table is *many-to-many* (**many** questions may use **many** keywords), so you have three tables. One holds the questions (one row per question), one holds the keywords (one row per keyword) and the third ties the two together. The `question_keywords` table will have multiple rows with the same questionID and multiple rows with the same keywordID. So if questionID 5 has three keywords, then there will be three entries in the `question_keywords` table with a questionID of 5.

For any *one-to-one* relationships, you are generally safe just making an additional column in the same table, so you will have one table for that relationship.

**NOTE:** Feel free to change the lengths of the `VARCHAR` columns. I picked values that might be OK, based on your examples, but if the questions and/or answers can be longer, then you may need to increase this size.

---

After creating these tables, you can populate them by doing something like this:

```
$query = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elements") or die(mysql_error());
echo "About to enter while-loop<br />";
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "loop ". $i++ ."<br />";
    $answerID = -1;

    $querystr = "SELECT answerID FROM answers WHERE answer = '{$row["db_answer"]}'";
    echo "Getting answerID. query: {$querystr}<br />";
    $query = mysql_query($querystr) or die($mysql_error());
    if (!(list($answerID) = mysql_fetch_row($query)))
    {
        $querystr = "INSERT INTO answers (answer) VALUES ('{$row["db_answer"]}')";
        echo "Answer did not exist, inserting now. query: {$querystr}<br />";
        mysql_query($querystr) or die(mysql_error());
        $answerID = mysql_insert_id();
    }

    $querystr = "INSERT INTO questions (questionID, question, answerID) VALUES ('{$row["id"]}', '{$row["db_question"]}', '{$answerID}')";
    echo "Inserting question. query: {$querystr}<br />";
    mysql_query($querystr) or die(mysql_error());

    $keywords = explode(",", trim($row["db_keywords"], "[]"));
    echo "keywords = ". print_r($keywords, true) ."<br />";
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $keywordID = -1;
        $querystr = "SELECT keywordID FROM keywords WHERE keyword = '{$keyword}'";
        echo "Getting keywordID. query: {$querystr}<br />";
        $query = mysql_query($querystr) or die(mysql_error());
        if (!(list($keywordID) = mysql_fetch_row($query)))
        {
            $querystr = "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ('{$keyword}')";
            echo "Keyword did not exist, inserting now. query: {$querystr}<br />";
            mysql_query($querystr) or die(mysql_error());
            $keywordID = mysql_insert_id();
        }

        $querystr = "INSERT INTO question_keywords (questionID, keywordID) VALUES ('{$row["id"]}', '{$keywordID}')";
        echo "Inserting question keyword. query: {$querystr}<br />";
        mysql_query($querystr) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, and verified that the four tables are populated correctly, you no longer need to use the `elements` table at all. Just use those four tables (`questions`, `answers`, `keywords`, and `question_keywords`).

Comment: Second the idea to store the answer in a separate table.  It removes the possibility of update anomalies, and your question becomes moot.

I also recommend getting the multivalued field db_keywords out of there.  Have a separate keyword table and a junction table that matches questions up with appropriate keywords.

Comment: I think I'll follow the advice of using separate tables. The values (keywords, answers, questions) will all be vulnerable to change by the user via a PHP application I wrote, so it makes sense that I fix the structure now as opposed to later.

mdoyle: This would mean that I would have separate tables for Questions, Keywords, and Answers correct? Does the elimination of duplicate values help with query performance? And what do you mean by junction table?

Thanks for your help though, I will save this PHP script for future reference.

Comment: @jaredtehone: I agree with @mdoyle. You would actually have four tables: `questions`, `answers`, `keywords`, and `question_keywords`. It will be easier to describe this structure by updating my answer, so I'll do that.

Comment: In the structure by @Travesty3, the junction table is question_keywords.  Also called a bridge table, it's the standard method for handling many-to-many relationships--here, between questions and keywords.  The elimination of the redundant data caused by db_answer in the questions table will help with query performance and reduce space requirements.  Most importantly it will eliminate update and insert anomalies (think of adding a new question and then typing in the answer, but typing it a bit differently:  Same answer in reality, but it your system it now looks like a different one).

Comment: Breaking the keywords out into a different table will vastly improve queries for those:  As a multivalued field, you would need to search using wildcards and would therefore be unable to take advantage of an index; as the questions table got large, searches for specific keywords would become very slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, to the both of you. Getting this kind of advice from a SQL information page is often hard because of the ambiguity of the information they provide. Having a custom answer to my needs really helps, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Travesty, I've been busy lately and just got to creating the tables. I have the four separate tables but I'm having trouble using the answer_id script for giving the questions their correct answer_id assignment. It works, however it skips groups (leaving them NULL) seemingly at random. I've looked for patterns in the skipping but cannot, for the life of me, find what is happening.

Comment: I think I might know the problem. My current elements table (the structure I'm trying to move away from, but still want to use for the purpose of assigning answer_ids) uses its element_id as the primary key. Whenever an element is found, assigned an answer_id, and then found later in the table, it is given a NULL value. I need the script to group by the duplicate answers.

Comment: @jaredtehone: See updated answer for a new PHP script you can use to populate these tables.

Comment: Travesty, is there any particular reason that this script wouldn't do anything to the tables? I have made sure that the tables are all created and coincide with the script names. PHP is not generating any errors...

Comment: @jaredtehone: See updated script. Not sure why it wouldn't do anything, but you should try some debugging. I added some `echo` statements so you can see the course that the script takes and all the queries that are executed. Perhaps that will help you find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Within the limits of mysql, you can assign an id to the answer as:

```
select answer, min(id) as answer_id
from table
group by answer
```

So, the complete solution is to create an answerid column in the table and then do something like:

```
with aid as 
(
  select answer, min(id) as answer_id
  from table
  group by answer
)
update table
set answer_id = aid.answer_id
where table.answer = aid.answer
```

Comment: I will give this a try, in addition to the above solution. Thanks for taking the time to give it a shot, I wish I could give you a +rep.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do this in a query is the SQL Server function ROW_NUMBER().  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have this.  However, you can emulate the function by taking advantage of inline assignment of variables.  Here is an article that explains the logic involved: http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/